# Moving one element alters unrelated elements, how can I 'detach' them?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

In draw.io diagrams that become moderately complicated, I often find that moving or resizing a line or box has unexpected side-effects... other elements are somehow 'glued' to it. So dragging a box might move one end of a line.
It's always when there is some element of overlap but I cannot see how I've done this or any visual clue which items are linked until I move something. Worse, sometimes these effects are subtle so my diagram might become broken.

What is this functionality called and how can I control it?

Comment: I've run in to the same behaviour, did you ever figure this out? The objects aren't grouped together and when you paste an item you have no choice where it goes and it can get glued to the thing it is pasted on to!

Answer (score -1):

Can you attach a video showing the exact steps and the result? If you hover a shape and click light blue arrows then a line is connected to a shape. This is default behaviour.